# Drupal, php.ini and Call to undefined function mysqli_real_escape_string error

Tags: drupal, iis, drupal-6

I've a Drupal website no Windows IIS on godaddy.

I've changed the php memory_limit using a root directory level php.ini file (from 32M to 64M).

However, when I run Drupal (in a subfolder) I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_real_escape_string() in D:\Hosting\3790877\html\fuzion\includes\database.mysqli.inc on line 330
```

If I remove the php.ini file, drupal runs correctly.

What's the issue ?
thanks

Comment: check if you have mysqli extension enabled at all in your php.ini.You do need php5 to get the mysqli extension and that extension must be enabled.The error means that the mysqli extension is not enabled in php

Comment: @ayush cool thanks. I've php5.2 installed. Should the directory level php.ini contain the entire configuration lines ? I thought I only need to add the lines I want to replace.

Comment: For example, my php5.ini file in the root directory of my hosting filesystem has only 1 line: memory_limit = 64M; Isn't the rest inherited by the main php.ini configuration ?

Comment: let me put all of this as an answer.with php.ini settings lines to you need to have .

Comment: @ayush thanks, I'm refreshing the page :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**check if you have mysqli extension enabled at all in your php.ini.You do need php5 to get the mysqli extension and that extension must be enabled.The error means that the mysqli extension is not enabled in php**

Here are the php.ini lines that you need to check for-

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll

[MySQLi]

; Maximum number of links.  -1 means no limit.
mysqli.max_links = -1

; Default port number for mysqli_connect().  If unset, mysqli_connect() will use
; the $MYSQL_TCP_PORT or the mysql-tcp entry in /etc/services or the
; compile-time value defined MYSQL_PORT (in that order).  Win32 will only look
; at MYSQL_PORT.
mysqli.default_port = 3306

; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
mysqli.default_socket =

; Default host for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
mysqli.default_host =

; Default user for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
mysqli.default_user =

; Default password for mysqli_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
; Note that this is generally a *bad* idea to store passwords in this file.
; *Any* user with PHP access can run 'echo get_cfg_var("mysqli.default_pw")
; and reveal this password!  And of course, any users with read access to this
; file will be able to reveal the password as well.
mysqli.default_pw =

; Allow or prevent reconnect
mysqli.reconnect = Off

[mSQL]
; Allow or prevent persistent links.
msql.allow_persistent = On

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
msql.max_persistent = -1

; Maximum number of links (persistent+non persistent).  -1 means no limit.
msql.max_links = -1
```

edit them acc. to your requirements.

Regarding your other question about the main php.ini and php.ini in other sub directories see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214431/how-do-i-enable-my-php-ini-file-to-affect-all-directories-sub-directories-of-my-s) and [this](http://www.askapache.com/php/custom-phpini-tips-and-tricks.html)

Comment: Thanks, so.. just to be clear. If I don't add any additional php.ini file I have mysql module enabled (phpinfo.php). So, I'm now going to add the lines you wrote here to my local php5.ini file. This sounds really strange to me, however, because directory level files shouldn't remove functionalities if not explicitly requested.

Comment: Also, another issue is that I dunno which value should mysqli.default_socket has... isn't a bit strange I have to set such variables twice (global and local configuration) ?

Comment: @Patrick: these lines should be present  in both php.ini. They should be present by default(i.e already there) in your local php.ini. php probably overrides the global php.ini file with a local set of rules on a per-directory basis (much like .htaccess). so have the same mysqli.default socket in both files. hope i was some help if not exact.

Comment: ok.. in the end I don't have access to the main php.ini so I don't know the values. I've solved differently: I've added ini_set("memory_limit","128M"); to Drupal php code.